# Positioning the content of a div on another div

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why the `float: right` doesn't work on the other box.
Anyone who can help me about this?

This is my code:

```css
.main-box {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}
.right-box {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.left-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.bottom-boxes {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
  <div class="top-boxes">
    <div class="right-box"></div>
    <div class="left-box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-boxes">
    <div class="right-box"></div>
    <div class="left-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the resulting image of my code:

[image: image1]

This is the resulting image I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `position: absolute` on `bottom-boxes` so you need to add `width: 100%`

```css
.main-box {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}
.right-box {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.left-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.bottom-boxes {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
  <div class="top-boxes">
    <div class="right-box"></div>
    <div class="left-box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-boxes">
    <div class="right-box"></div>
    <div class="left-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But here is better solution using [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

```css
.main-box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: black;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5wrwap5/)

When you put absolute position on a container, you have to specify also top, right and left property with bottom property to set a width and a height of it.

```
.bottom-boxes{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

In this case, `left: 0;` and `right: 0;` are equivalent to `width: 100%;` and `top: 0` and `bottom: 0;` are equivalent to `height: 100%;`

When you don't specify a value, by default it's "`auto;`"

Answer (score 0):

`float` won't work on an absolutely positioned element - you need to give `top`  *or* `bottom` and `right` *or* `left` parameters to it (the default setting is `top: 0;` and `left: 0;`, i.e. the upper left corner of the parent element).